# undefined reference to `GOIO_SET' linux

Tags: linux

I have written a macro for set function shown in below and working on raspberry pi

```
#define GPIO_SET(g) (*(gpio.addr + 7) |= (1<<(g)))

#define ALL_COL_HIGH    (GPIO_SET(COL1) | GOIO_SET(COL2) | GPIO_SET(COL3) | GPIOO
_SET(COL4))
```

when i compile file I will get following error

```
**undefined reference to `GOIO_SET'**
```

how can i overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that you define `GPIO_SET` but then use `GOIO_SET`? The second letter is different! A `P` in the definition, but a `O` in the use. Also there are other typo in the last one: `GPIOO_SET` has two `O`.

Since the `GOIO_SET` name is not defined, the compiler thinks it must be a function or something, but it is not defined, so it gives you the error.

As a side note, I think that your code is wrong. Your `ALL_COL_HIGH` macro will expand to something like:

```
(*(gpio.addr + 7) |= (1<<(COL1))) | (*(gpio.addr + 7) |= (1<<(COL2))) ...
```

That will modify the same value (`*(gpio.addr + 7)`) several times without intermediate sequence points, and that is undefined behavior.

You can solve this with the comma operator, since the `|` in `ALL_COL_HIGH` is meaningless:

```
#define ALL_COL_HIGH (GPIO_SET(COL1) , GPIO_SET(COL2) , GPIO_SET(COL3) , GPIO_SET(COL4))
```

The comma operator does include a sequence point, so all will be fine.

Although it is usually easier to define the COLx values as the real bits and set all at the same time.

```
#define COL1 (1<<1)
#define COL2 (1<<2)
#define COL3 (1<<3)
#define COL4 (1<<4) //or whatever

#define GPIO_SET(g) (*(gpio.addr + 7) |= (g))
#define ALL_COL_HIGH (GPIO_SET(COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4))
```